# Custom navigation from term store to sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-extensions

I would like to add custom global navigation from term store to sharepoint online using spfx extension.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by creating an [SPFx application customiser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/overview-extensions) and utilising the [top placeholder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/using-page-placeholder-with-extensions).

Your application customiser can utilise the [Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/termstore-term?view=graph-rest-1.0) to access the managed metadata service.

Comment: I have followed this https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/global-navigation-in-modern-sharepoin-using-spfx-pnp-and-fluent-ui/ and tried the term store but ended with "Error: Error making HttpClient request in queryable [400] ::> {"error":{"code":"invalidRequest","message":"Failed to parse the termGroupId."}}"

Comment: You'll need to consult the documentation and ensure you're using the correct syntax.